# Is it okay to declare variable without useState in functional components ? React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am curious to know which one perform better. Two of the example run correctly without warning, but is it acceptable to declare mutable variable in react without useState ? (Example using react query for data fetching)

Ex 1 :

```
let flexibleName = ""

const { data, status } = useQuery("users", fetchUsers)

if(data) flexibleName = "TEST DATA"

return <div>{flexibleName}</div>
```

Ex 2 :

```
const [flexibleName, setFlexibleName] = useState("")

const { data, status } = useQuery("users", fetchUsers)

useEffect(()=>{
  if(!data) return
  setFlexibleName("TEST DATA")
},[data])

return <div>{flexibleName}</div>
```

Comment: This will work, ant in case of performance, there is propablo not a big problem. But you variable will not be rememberet through rerenders, and you lost every data you store in it from user interaction, and if you change it, it will not be seen in html, because it will not cause rerender.

Comment: and in your ex2, you are setting it wrong, this will be also lost after rerender, because you are not calling `setFlexibleName("TEST DATA")`

Answer (score 5):

> Is it acceptable to declare mutable variable in react without
> `useState`?

Yes, it's ok to do so. `flexibleName` appears to be derived state (*derived from `data`*), and as such doesn't belong in React state. Use the first example.

```
const { data, status } = useQuery("users", fetchUsers);

const flexibleName = data ? "TEST DATA" : "";

return <div>{flexibleName}</div>;
```

If you need to you can memoize the `flexibleName` value with the `useMemo` hook.

```
const { data, status } = useQuery("users", fetchUsers);

const flexibleName = useMemo(() => {
  return data ? "TEST DATA" : "";
}, [data]);

return <div>{flexibleName}</div>;
```

See [Identify the Minimal (but complete) Representation of UI State](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) for more details regarding derived state.

> Ask three questions about each piece of data:
>
> 1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 3. Can you compute it ***based on any other state or props*** in your component? If so, it isn’t state.

Note the emphasis is mine.

Computing the derived state also avoids the unnecessary rerenders just to update some state for display. ***Or*** another way to think about it is that the `useMemo` hook is like combining the `useState` and `useEffect` hooks to update and memoize a value without triggering the additional rerender.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is actually better to not use state.

As explained in this [article](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state) from the React team, using a state will cause an unnecessary rerender of the component when the `flexibleName` variable is modified.
Quoting the [documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state):

> If you can calculate some information from the component’s props or its existing state variables during rendering, you should not put that information into that component’s state.

Also, in your example, the `setFlexibleName` is a function to you should call it like `setFlexibleName("TEST DATA")`